# Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer - File Changes Detected keeps popping up

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm sending log files from my ASP.net application directly to Microsoft Azure Storage, which is working fine. However, I keep having a dialog pop up in the Azure Storage Explorer that says "File Changes Detected"

'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\157264315013847\06082020_log.log' has been modified by an external program. How do you want to handle the changes?

No matter which option I select a second later the dialog pops up again with the file being modified in a different folder in ...\Local\Temp

Why are these files constantly being added to this Temp folder and how do I make it stop?

Comment: You should also raise this issue here: https://aka.ms/storageexplorer/issues.

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot? and which version of `Storage Explorer` are you using? and for the blob, it's append blob or block blob?

Comment: @IvanYang I'm using version 11.1.7 and append blob

Comment: @stormynight19023, can you tell us which version of Storage Explorer you're using? and it's better to provide a sample code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hi , did you find any clue about this?